# How to catch xmlhttprequest error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I've got an ajax call and I keep running into an error when a bad request is made. It does work when a good request is made. I've already tried jsonp and all that stuff but that didn't help me any further.

This is the errow

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is my code.

```
var submit = function(){
        var url = ""
        var data = ["9b4e749d5cb6e069dd49cab93a69","aufujishngidrg"]
        for(var int = 0; int < data.length; int++) {
            console.log(data[int])
            url = *insert url*
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:encodeURI(url),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error:function (xmlHttpRequest,textStatus, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0){
                        console.log("xmlhttpRequest error")
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("error")
                    }
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                },
            });
        }
        console.log("derp")
    }
```

I send a hashcode from a list and the server returns an id if it is in the database.

Cross domain communication is enabled on the server side so that should not be the problem, hence good requests do work. When an unknown hash is in the list I get this htttpxmlrequest error and the loop breaks.

The question is: how do I catch the error and keep iterating?

Comment: Can you fix the server-side code so it doesn't bomb when the record doesn't exist?

Comment: If it errors out, are you able to use the `continue;` keyword to continue iterations through the loop?

Comment: @lfender6445 No, it either thorws an illigel continue statement error or makes no difference at all.

Comment: I might actually try that, @JasonP

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ajax call in a try catch statement to swallow the error

```
try {
  $.ajax{
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest,textStatus, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      throw(thrownError)
    }
    success: function(){}
   }
} catch(err) {
  continue;
}
```